# mysql conflicting where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, ambiguity

I have the following tables:

```
users: id, username, password, created, modified
posts: id, user_id, message, created, modified
```

I am trying to run a query that gets the last 5 posts that were created today (as well as the username of the poster).  When I run the following query:

```
SELECT users.username, posts.*
FROM postsLEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (posts.user_id=users.id)
WHERE (DATE(`posts.created`) = DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY posts.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I get the message:

> Unknown column 'posts.created' in 'where clause'

Which is fine, I understand that the where is run before the other parts of the query.  So then I try this query:

```
SELECT users.username, posts.*
FROM postsLEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (posts.user_id=users.id)
WHERE (DATE(`created`) = DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY posts.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But of course I get the message:

> Column 'created' in where clause is ambiguous

Any suggestions on how to alter the query so there aren't any issues?

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping items.created in quotes it's interpreted as a column named "items.created" rather than the created column from the items table.  The below should work.

```
SELECT users.username, items.*
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (items.user_id=users.id)
WHERE (DATE(items.created) = DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY items.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```